# Import Flex Project as a component?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

I'm building a Flex App for a Media Development course and one of our requirements for this sprint is to implement a simple P2P chat into the interface.  I created one from a tutorial that served my needs and altered it appropriately, but it exists as a separate Flex Project and not within the Main App.

I know I can export the Chat as an fxp project file, but I'm not sure how I can use it in my main app.  I was trying to create a Custom Component, but the process isn't very clear and Adobe's help files on the subject didn't seem to relate to what I specifically wanted to do.  I get the feeling that there's a very simple fix for my goal, but hopefully someone would able to point me in the right direction as I've been working on this app for a good 6 hours and need a break.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a library project; not a Flex Project.

The output of a library project is a SWC; which can be used in other projects.  The output of a Flex Project is a SWF which cannot be used in other projects.

The fxp export is a project export; for sharing project settings between different instances of Flash Builder.

Most likely You'll need to create a library project, move the appropriate files over to it; and then add that library SWC to the library path of your main project.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I knew it was going to be something simple like that...

Comment: I seem to be stuck again.  I created a library project and since the P2P chat project consisted of a single MXML script, I simply copied the MXML from the project and created a new MXML Component in my library project and pasted the working code there.  I can see that upon build it creates an SWC file in the bin folder, but when I created a new Flex Project for my main app and linked that SWC, I can see it in the referenced libraries, but I don't know how to add the chat I created to my main app.  Sorry, kind of new to the Flex Environment.

Comment: @ecarv141 Add your Chat component to you main application the same way you add any other component.,  Create an instance of the class and add it to a parent using addChild() or addElement() (for Spark Components).

Comment: So in my Flex Library project, should I put the code into an AS Class file?   The tutorial had me build it in MXML as a separate Flex Project, the code can be found here - http://pastebin.com/R1PN8SaB

If I put that in an AS Class instead of MXML and then place the SWC in my lib folder for my main app, can I then reference it?

I just didn't know how to use addChild since it was in MXML and didn't actually have a class name.

Comment: @ecarv141 MXML files are components too.  No need to force your code into an AS file.  In MXML the addChild() piece is hidden, but still occurs.  IF you have an MXML component, you can use your component in the library just like any other component.  Import the namespace and create the child like this: <myNameSpace:MyComponentName />

Comment: Okay, so just to double check:  Create Flex Library Project > Create MXML Component > Add code for P2P chat (this creates the UI for it as well) > Put SWC into main app's libs folder > ?  That's where I get stuck. It would be great if it showed in the Custom Components panel to just drop in.  I don't know what a namespace is (newness showing again) so I'm not sure how to import it.  I assume 'MyComponentName' is just the name of the MXML file.  Does the MXML Component have to be in my src folder or can I import it as long as the SWC is in my libs folder? Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: It should show up in the custom components section of design view, but design view never worked right; and there are lots of version issues with it depending on your Flex SDK and the version of Flash Builder you are using.  In MXML, you should be able to just start typing the name of your component <MyComp />  And it should show up in code hinting.  Once it does, select it press enter and the namespace should import automatically.

Comment: I got it working now, thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it!